# json comes in as object not string

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jsonp

Json is sitting on my localhost as: /data/:

```
{
"children": [
    {
        "name": "analytics",
        "size": "1243"
    },
    {
        "name": "math",
        "size": "4343"
    },
    {
        "name": "algebra",
        "size": "1936"
    },
    {
        "name": "calc",
        "size": "3936"
    },
    {
        "name": "geom",
        "size": "2136"
    },
    {
        "name": "Quant",
        "size": "4136"
    }
]
```

}

Here is how I am trying to access the json:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/dev_tests/d3/examples/data/flare2.json", function(json) {
            $.each(json.children,function(i,name){
            alert(json.children);
            });

        });
        }, 3000);
```

The data comes in just fine. That is, when I run *console.log(json)* I can see the above json name/value txt pairs in firebug. However, before each name value pair I see the word Object. So for example instead of my log showing { name="analytics", size="1243"},.. it actually shows: [Object { name="analytics", size="1243"},... And that too is what my alert shows: *[object Object]* instead of *name="analytics", size="1243"*. 
Why is this and is there a way to get my json name/value pairs in text so that I can store as a javascript String?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *O* in JSON stands for "object."  It's a way of serializing a JavaScript object to a string (and back).  You seem to be relying on the conversion on one hand (referencing `children`) but not want to have the conversion done on the other hand.  If you really want `children` to be a collection of strings in the format you describe, you should store it that way.  If you really do want the object notation (and conversion to objects in the client), then you can simply use the properties of the object.

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/dev_tests/d3/examples/data/flare2.json", function(json) {
        $.each(json.children,function(i,item){
           alert("name = " + item.name + ", size = " + item.size);
        });

    });
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhh! I see... That's it. Finally. I could not get this delineation (obj to str) to click. Thank you so much for this!!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery does automatically decode the response when using [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) or specifying the response as JSON. If you want the plain response, use [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead.

Comment: Actually, jQuery.getJSON is shorthand for the ajax call. See the jQuery.getJSON page for the ajax method.

Comment: @JessevanAssen well not exactly `$.getJSON` sets the `dataType:json` implicitly where as with `$.ajax` you have the flexibility of specifying the `dataType` to `text` etc

Comment: No, what I mean is that the `jQuery.getJSON` actually calls the `jQuery.ajax` method with some default parameters, as seen on the [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) page.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you've stated is normal behavior for both firebug and alert. You can't alert an object.

Here's example of how to loop the response within your $.get callback

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3N4S/

```
$.each(json.children, function(i, item){
    $('body').append('<p>Name: '+item.name+' , Size: '+item.size+'</p>')

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, working with Objects is the intend of ["Javascript Object Notation"](http://json.org/).

Actually, your json is an Array of Objects.

```
{
  "children": [ // <-- Array
          {...},// <- Object
          {...} // <- Object
  ]
}
```

You can access your key-value pairs this way: `children[0].name`

```
for (var i=0;i< children.length; ++){
    console.log( children[i].name);
    console.log( children[i].size);
}
```